# How specialize member type for a derived class in C#?

Tags: c#

I would like to do something like this:

[image]

Where `Plan` has a `Contact` Property and there is a specialization of `Plan` and `Contact`.

I tried

```
abstract class Contact { }

class SpecialContact : Contact { }

abstract class Plan {
   public virtual Contact contact;
}

class SpecialPlan : Plan {
   public override SpecialContact contact;
}
```

But the type override are forbidden in C#.

How can I model this and specialize the sub property of a sub class?

I Just need to enforce that the `SpecialPlan` will only have  `SpecialContact`.. not any other `Contact`

Comment: Why do you need to extend Contact? Do you need to add methods or could you have Contact be an interface?

Comment: Unless you need to actually instantiate `Plan` and `Contact`, you could make them abstract base classes.  Or, you could use interfaces.  Or, you could encapsulate what differs between `Plan` and `SpecialPlan` and `Contact` and `SpecialContact` in various Strategy classes, which could be members of `Plan` and `Contact` respectively.  Remember: composition over inheritance

Comment: I Just want to enforce that the `SpecialPlan` will only have  `SpecialContact`.. not any other `Contact`

Comment: What is special about `SpecialPlan` and `SpecialContact`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void Main()
{
    var sp = new SpecialPlan();
    sp.Contact = new SpecialContact(); // new Contact(); won't compile
}

abstract class Contact
{
}

class SpecialContact : Contact
{
}

abstract class Plan<T> where T: Contact
{
    public T Contact { get; set; }
}

class SpecialPlan : Plan<SpecialContact>
{
}
```

If you want to override the get/set property.

```
void Main()
{
    var sp = new SpecialPlan();
    sp.Contact = new SpecialContact(); // new Contact(); won't compile
}

abstract class Contact
{
}

class SpecialContact : Contact
{
}

abstract class Plan<T> where T: Contact
{
    protected T contact;
    public virtual T Contact { get { return contact; } set { contact = value; } }
}

class SpecialPlan : Plan<SpecialContact>
{
    public override SpecialContact Contact { get { return contact; } set { contact = value; } }
}
```